# How to fetch the data which has multiple JSONObject in it

Tags: java, android, json, api, kotlin

Here is the JSON response which I have to fetch:

```
{
  "markets": [
    {
      "exchange_id": "BINANCE",
      "symbol": "BTC-USDT",
      "price_unconverted": 37193.095,
      "price": 37228.28172528144,
      "change_24h": -4.547427178236877,
      "spread": 0.000026886707486166165,
      "volume_24h": 3422591459.036938,
      "status": "recent",
      "time": "2021-06-04T22:41:01"
    },
    {
      "exchange_id": "BINANCE",
      "symbol": "ETH-USDT",
      "price_unconverted": 2734.6549999999997,
      "price": 2737.2421349029846,
      "change_24h": -3.7432242168250704,
      "spread": 0.0003656761718006455,
      "volume_24h": 3244286756.710182,
      "status": "recent",
      "time": "2021-06-04T22:41:01"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "next": "10"
  }
}
```

I have written the code for the 1st JSON Object which has the list of the array in it.
I want to know how could I fetch the 2nd JSON Object in my code so that I can get the whole JSON Object value.

My Code ->

val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://www.cryptingup.com/api/markets"

```
val jsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
    Response.Listener {

        try {

        val markets = it.getJSONArray("markets")
        for (i in 0 until markets.length()) {

            val marketJsonObject = markets.getJSONObject(i)
            val marketObject = Market(
                marketJsonObject.getString("exchange_id"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("symbol"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("price_unconverted"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("price"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("change_24th"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("spread"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("volume_24th"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("status"),
                marketJsonObject.getString("time")

            )
           marketList.add(marketObject)
            
                recyclerAdapter =
                    MarketRecyclerAdapter(this, marketList)

                recyclerMarket.adapter = recyclerAdapter

                recyclerMarket.layoutManager = layoutManager

        }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "$it JSON error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }, Response.ErrorListener {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Volley Error Occured $it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }){

    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"

        return headers
    }
}

queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

}

Comment: Move the "recycler" code outside the `for` loop, i.e. don't call `MarketRecyclerAdapter(...)` until `marketList` is filled with all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code it will help you.

```
     try {
       
        val marketsArray: JSONArray = it.getJSONArray("markets")
        for (countItem in 0 until marketsArray.length()) {
            val returnObject = marketsArray.getJSONObject(countItem)
            val exchangeId =
                if (returnObject.isNull("exchange_id")) "" else returnObject.optString("exchange_id")
            val symbol =
                if (returnObject.isNull("symbol")) "" else returnObject.optString("symbol")
        }
        val pagination: JSONObject = it.getJSONObject("pagination")
        val next = pagination.getString("next")
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On another note, have you tried to use kotlinx serialisation to map JSON objects, converted to string, to POJO?

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization